# Error launching a Java app from a Win32 C++ app using CreateProcess

Tags: java, c++, noclassdeffounderror, createprocess

I'm trying to launch a Java app from a C++ app using the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    STARTUPINFOW        siStartupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo;

    memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo));
    memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo)); 

    if (CreateProcess(TEXT("c:\\java\\jre\\bin\\java.exe"), TEXT("-jar testapp.jar"), NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, NULL, NULL, &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo) == false) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not load app", L"Error", 0);
    }

    CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

When I build and run the program I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: testapp/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testapp.jar
        at: java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Uknown Source)
        at: java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at: java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Uknown Source)
        at: java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Uknown Source)
        at: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Uknown Source)
        at: java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Uknown Source)
Could not find the main class: testapp.jar. Program will exit.
```

The `testapp.jar` file is a runnable JAR file exported from an Eclipse project with a single class in it:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

The EXE and JAR file are in the exact same folder, and I'm running the EXE from the command line. If I run the JAR directly by putting `c:\java\jre\bin\java.exe -jar testapp.jar` into the command-prompt everything works as expected.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

EDIT: Thank you all for your help, but it looks like I've got it working now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it. I used:

```
if (CreateProcess(TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\java.exe"), TEXT(" -jar test.jar"), NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, NULL, NULL, &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo) == false) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not load app", L"Error", 0);
    }
```

Whereas you've used:

```
if (CreateProcess(TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\java.exe"), TEXT("-jar test.jar"), NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, NULL, NULL, &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo) == false) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not load app", L"Error", 0);
    }
```

which, when I used it, replicates your error. The difference is a space preceding the `-jar` switch and why that should be, I don't know, I stumbled upon it in error!

Comment: I'll be honest, why is currently eluding me. I'll update the answer if I find out.

Comment: @gf I know. Discovered via an editing mistake, so I don't really deserve +1 or the answer but I've hit the rep limit anyway. Any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: @Ninefingers: A quick test shows that the Win32 API is so clever that it passes an empty entry as the first entry for `argv` if you use a leading space ...

Comment: @gf. Oh. Interesting... I did try the argument string as java.exe -jar ... with the program string as-is, but that produced the error again. Hmmm.

Answer (score 3):

I just had to change the way I was calling CreateProcess:

```
wchar_t *command = (wchar_t*)calloc(512, sizeof(wchar_t));

wsprintf(command, TEXT("c:\\java\\jre\\bin\\java.exe -jar testapp.jar"));

if (CreateProcess(NULL, command, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, NULL, NULL, &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo) == false) {
```

Comment: This one allows for you to use just "java.exe -jar testapp.jar" in the command vs "c:\\java\\jre\\bin\\java.exe -jar testapp.jar".
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175986

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `CreateProcess()` specifies for the parameter `lpCurrentDirectory`:

> The full path to the current directory for the process. The string can also specify a UNC path.
>   If this parameter is NULL, the new process will have the same current drive and directory as the calling process.

You excerpt is missing a definition for `path`, but most likely it is set up incorrectly.

Comment: Sorry, that's an error in the code I pasted. The line should be:
     CreateProcess(TEXT("c:\\java\\jre\\bin\\java.exe"), TEXT("-jar testapp.jar"), NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, NULL, NULL, &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo)

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the directory of the JAR after `-jar`. It could have to do with your current working directory...